# One-to-one function trigonometric function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Consider the function f (x) = (sin x)(cos x). True or false: There exists a number a such that f is one-to-one over the closed interval [a, a + π ]. (If true, prove it. If false, find a counterexample.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$. Show that $f(a)=f(a+\pi)$ for any $a$.

Comment: As Matthew Holder observed, since $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x\cos x$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$.  Try graphing $f(x)$.  Is it one-to-one over an interval of length $\pi$?